# google_metadata process consuming 100% CPU in Google Compute Engine instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm using Google Compute Engine instance (f1.micro). Since google_metadata process (Python) is consuming CPUs. (Because of this Google Cloud Console suggests "Consider switching to the machine type: g1-small (1 vCPU, 1.7 GB memory)").

Does anyone know what the process is for and how can we remediate this situation?

```
top - 14:47:46 up 10 min,  1 user,  load average: 1.10, 1.12, 0.70
Tasks:  82 total,   2 running,  80 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 83.6 us, 16.4 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:    608416 total,   498272 used,   110144 free,    20868 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.   310984 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                    
  744 root      20   0   31416  15452   6188 R 99.9  2.5   8:56.75 google_metadata                            
    1 root      20   0   96548   5784   3832 S  0.0  1.0   0:01.07 systemd                                    
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                   
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.04 ksoftirqd/0                                
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H                               
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.06 rcu_sched                                  
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh                                     
    9 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0                                
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/0                                 
   11 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs                                  
   12 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns                                      
   13 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 perf                                       
   14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khungtaskd                                 
   15 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 writeback                                  
   16 root      39  19       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khugepaged                                 
   17 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 crypto                                     
   18 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd                                
   19 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset                                     
   20 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd                                    
   21 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata_sff                                    
suztomo@light-composer ~ $ ps -ef |grep google_metadata
root       744     1 90 14:37 ?        00:09:01 /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/lib/python-exec/python2.7/google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the process is responsible to run "startup-script" in metadata of Google Compute Engine virtual machines, which usually stops after such script. However, in my settings, the startup script runs forever to continuously run some commands, and unexpectedly caused the high-CPU issue.

Remediation would be not to have such long-running startup-script.